# Yii2 Bootstrap navbar's label URL without clean URL

Tags: yii2, clean-urls

I still under development and I don't want to use clean URLs in my Yii2 right now.

I added the following code to the advanced Yii2 project navbar `About` to make submenu under About:

```
[
    'label' => 'About',
    'url' => ['/site/about'],
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Invoices', 'url' => 'invoices/index'],
    ]
],
```

Normally, the `invoices` controller is accessed by: `/?r=invoices` from the client's address bar. However, the above code generates `/invoices/index` which gives `Page not found error` because I did not enabled clean URLs yet.

My question is, how could I add, accessible, new menu items as regarded above without clean URLs enabled while keeping the code as it is after enabling clean URLs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`url` parameter value is processed by [\yii\helpers\Url::to()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to%28%29-detail) method:

> - `false` (default): generating a relative URL.
> - `true`: returning an absolute base URL whose scheme is the same as that in [\yii\web\UrlManager::hostInfo](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$hostInfo-detail).
> - string: generating an absolute URL with the specified scheme (either `http` or `https`).

So if you pass a string to `url` parameter, it will be treated as absolute url. In order to create url for given route, you need to pass array, then it will be processed by [\yii\helpers\Url::toRoute()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#toRoute%28%29-detail):

```
'url' => ['invoices/index'],
```

It will consider [UrlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html) settings, such as [$enablePrettyUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$enablePrettyUrl-detail).